# Add a "before you ask" section to tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, help

Quite often, I'd like to comment on a question with some "before asking a question about `tag` you should..." direct link.

For example, to point out that the OP should try to use a debugger first.

Would that be possible?

For example, this section could be in most popular tag wikis with an anchor.

Comment: Some sites do have notes like this in their tag wikis already - eg [this Android tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). Are you suggesting a specific new field that would stand out more?

Comment: Maybe the content in this field could be shown as a tag warning? However that may require a higher rep requirement to suggest an edit.

Comment: @TimMalone, I think about something like that indeed. For example, javascript tag has such a section in the tag wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), but without direct link

Comment: On adding a warning with such information, there's also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191436/make-tags-even-more-helpful